# Problem instaling Newtonsoft.Json library in VS2019

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2019

I would like to use a Newtonsoft.Json library in VS2019.
I am trying to install it with nuget.
When I select the library in nuget, click to install it on my current project, I get a really strange error:

```
Error       Failed to fetch results from V2 feed at 'https://github.com/XiaoFaye/WooCommerce.NET/FindPackagesById()?id='Newtonsoft.Json'&semVerLevel=2.0.0' with following message : Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).
```

Why is it trying to install it from "https://github.com/XiaoFaye/WooCommerce.NET"?

I have tried installing it in a new project, I have deleted and reinstall visual studio.

On another computer, the installation work just fine...

Thanks!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio#package-sources

Comment: Double check what NuGet package sources you have set up at Tools | Options | NuGet Package Manager | Package Sources. It looks like, for whatever reason, another source has been added that is using an old version of the NuGet web API that VS2019 no longer supports.

Answer (score 1):

You can install it directly from VS.
Right click on your project name and choose **Manage NuGet Packages** option.
Go to Browse tab and search **Newtonwnsoft.json**.
click to install.
Hope it will help you.

Comment: That is exactly what I did! But it displays the error, I have listed in my question.

Comment: open package manger console and then try this and make sure your package source must be **nuget.org**: **Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json**

Comment: Hi! Using the console installation everything is fine! Thank you!